# How to make the mask image fit the container?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

So I have one PNG image which supposed to be masked with another canvas meaning im converting the 2nd canvas to DataURL and make it a mask image of the PNG Image. How do I make mask image to fit whole in the PNG Image?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(canvas2DataUrl, function (img) {
   img.set({
      id: "PK3000Layer1Mask",
      left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200,
      top: 5 + 20 + 80,
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",
      selectable: false,
      addedByLoadBase000: true,
      // scaleY: PK3Layer1000.height / PK3Layer1000.width,
      // scaleX: PK3Layer1000.width / PK3Layer1000.width,
    });
    img.set("dirty", true);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer1000, function (clipImage) {
      img.clipPath = clipImage;
      clipImage.set({
        selectable: false,
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    });

    canvas.insertAt(img, canvas.getObjects().length);
});
```

So apparently in canvas2 there's only a specific spot where the added objects can be seen which supposed to be the whole canvas. What Im trying to do is the whole canvas to be seen there.

[Spot in canvas2 where image can only be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiMia.png)